# Setting up Rails5 Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I was following DHH's tutorial. All going well until I added this code to room.coffee

```
$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13 # return = send
  App.room.speak event.target.value
  event.target.value = ''
  event.preventDefault()
```

As soon as I do this, I get:

> SyntaxError: [stdin]:15:3: unexpected if

Extracted source (around line #8):

```
6    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
7
8    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
9    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </head>
```

I am using Rails 5.0.0.beta2, Ruby 2.3.0, and running on OS X 10.11.3

Odd that the error appears to be in `application.html.erb` when I change something (to code that appears to be correct?) on `room.coffee`

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That a Javascript error is unrelated to Action Cable. You get it because your `if` has no body.

Your code, as it is currently indented, translates to something that makes no sense, hence the error

```
$(document).on('keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13)
    App.room.speak(event.target.value);
    event.target.value = '';        
    return event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is what you want. Notice the indentation.

```
$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13 # return = send
    App.room.speak event.target.value
    event.target.value = ''
    event.preventDefault()
```

It translates to

```
$(document).on('keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        App.room.speak(event.target.value);
        event.target.value = '';        
        return event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Embarrassing - my bad. Sorted out so easily. Many thanks for the very quick answer.